# Get full App Call Graph in KCacheGrind

Tags: php, profiling, kcachegrind

I want get full graph of my script using KCacheGrind, it this possible?

Comment: What do you mean with *full*? If you select the `main (100%)` root branch, KCacheGrind should show you the full graph...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

> - [Profiling a PHP Application](https://erichogue.ca/2011/03/linux/profiling-a-php-application/)

- [A 'profiler with visualization' for PHP with `full backtrace visualization`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810437/a-profiler-with-visualization-for-php-with-full-backtrace-visualization)

I would suggest using `xhprof` for its `better Call-Graph` and `data presentation`.

Check this link there are 2 screenhots in the **XHGui** section: [Profiling a PHP Application](https://erichogue.ca/2011/03/linux/profiling-a-php-application/)

Here is a screenshot of the CallGraph from the above link:

[image: CallGraph]
<sub>(source: [erichogue.ca](https://erichogue.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/XHGuiCallGraph.png))</sub>

> Although, *XHProf does not provide full backtrace. XHProf keeps track of only one level of calling context and is therefore only able to answer questions about a function looking either one level up or down.*